# How do I multiply more than two matrices in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, parameters

I am sending in an **array of references** and here is my subroutine:

```
sub multiply
{
    my @product;

    my $ref1 = $_[0];
    my $ref2 = $_[1];

    my @array1 = @$ref1;
    my @array2 = @$ref2;


    }
    my ($rowsA,$columnsA) = &dimensions(@$ref1);
    my ($rowsB,$columnsB) = &dimensions(@$ref2);

    for $i (0..$rowsA-1){
    for $j (0..$columnsB-1){
            for $k (0..$columnsA-1){
                    $product[$i][$j] += $array1[$i][$k] * $array2[$k][$j];
            }
    }
 }
```

This subroutine works for two parameters, but how do I multiply the matrices when more than two parameters are sent?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `@_` array directly.  You won't be able to assign your references directly as you have in your example b/c as you have found, you don't know the number of items being passed.  The good thing is, you don't need too.  All arguments are passed to Perl sub-routines via the special @_ array.  When you see `my $x = shift;` this array is where the data is being shifted from into your local variables.  Here, since you can't know ahead of time how many vars to create, you can use the array directly.  Typical array functions apply.  (i.e. to get size you can use scalar(@_))

The following example displays the type of sub-routine you would write using regular scalars.  It would be the same for references, you would just need to dereference them prior to their use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $result = multiply(2,4,5);
print "Result 1: $result\n";

$result = multiply(2,2);
print "Result 2: $result\n";

$result = multiply(2,2,3,5,6);
print "Result 3: $result\n";


sub multiply
{
    my $ans = 1;
    foreach my $x (@_) { $ans *= $x; }
    return $ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be combined with RC's answer, which explains what @_ is and how to use it, you can also recurse:

```
sub multiply {
  return $_[0] * $_[1] if @_ <= 2;
  return shift( @_ ) * multiply( @_ );
}
```

It won't be as fast as his answer, but for more complex tasks, can be easier to implement.